# How to debug the openjdk 9 (mainly the hotspot) source code in Eclipse?

Tags: jvm, java

I want to debug the hotspot source code , such as set some breakpoints in the Native Code,to learn it.
So I built the openjdk 9 source code by the Eclipse and successfully, and below is built setting and the output of the built.

[image: Builder setting and built output folder]

Then I tried to configure the "Debug Configurations", however I don't know how to set the c/c++ application, someone advise it to "openjdk/hotspot/build/Linux/linux_amd64_compiler2/jvmg" for JDK 7 , however I cannot find it in the built output folder for jdk 9, I tried to set it to "~/jdk9/build/linux-x86_64-normal-server-fastdebug/jdk/java" then click  button "debug" to debug it, however it failed with information "No source code available for main".
So my question is 1,)how to do the setting to let me debug the jdk source code successfully? 2,) If there are other places I need to set?
[image]

Comment: The issue fixed by setting the debug level to slowdebug  .

Comment: i am new to openjdk. can you please guide me a bit about how to locate or edit the bytecode instruction set

Comment: Sorry adeel, I am also new to JVM, I think you can post the new question at SO, and some JVM experts like apangin would help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue fixed by setting the debug level to slowdebug for the JDK 9

Comment: Do you have problem like `Thread 0x7ffff7fc8700 (LWP 74169) "java" 0x00007fffe0dde513 in ?? ()`    ?

Comment: No, it didn't, what's your version for Linux and IDE ?

Comment: My linux version is 16.10 Ubuntu, and IDE is Eclipse 64 bit (most updated one)

Comment: @YuFengShen so you compiled the jdk with slowdebug level and then selected java executable in your run configuration ? i currently try to do the same thing for OpenJDK8 but facing a fail. Would appreaciate any help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51928839/debugging-openjdk-source-code-with-eclipse)

Comment: @Aksim, sorry I also failed to debug the native code by gdb, I just debug the native code by elipse(c++ version) .